# Databse explorer/Server explorer missing Visual Studio express 2013

Tags: visual-studio-express, server-explorer

Here am not able to see Data Connections

like in the screenshot below

[image]

How to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go To :
View -> Server Explorer/ Database Explorer
Link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd2cz7yy.aspx

Comment: Really ? In Express edition ? In 2012 express it seems  to be not available,

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio 2012 Express its named as **Database Explporer**

**View->Other Windows -> Database Explorer**
OR **Press Ctrl+W,L**